# Define subpackages for variadic templates in C++

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I have something like that based on variadic templates:

```
class MyClass {
  public:
    template <typename... OtherTs>
    typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(OtherTs) == 0>::type Setup() {}

    template <typename T, typename...OtherTs>
    void Setup() {
      DoSomeStuff(new T());
      Setup<OtherTs>();
    }
};
```

It's working well and I can setup an instantiation of `MyClass` based on other classes like that `myClass.Setup<A,B,C>()`.
What I would like to do now is to define subpackages of classes like `Default = A, B` such that `myClass.Setup<Default, C>()` or even `myClass.Setup<MyClass::Default, C>()` will be interpreted as `myClass.Setup<A,B,C>()`.

I know I can define `#define Default A, B` but is there a similar way that does not rely on macro and could be defined in a namespace/class?

Thanks for reading and have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use recursion when tuple or any specific type (`tag` here) is given:

```
template <typename...> struct tag{};

class MyClass {
private:
    template <typename T>
    void SetupImpl(tag<T>)
    {
        // Here, individual setup
        DoSomeStuff(new T());
    }
    template <typename ...Ts>
    void SetupImpl(tag<tag<Ts...>>)
    {
        Setup<Ts...>();
    }

public:
    template <typename ... Ts>
    void Setup() {
      (SetupImpl(tag<Ts>{}), ...); // C++17 fold expression
    }
};

using Default = tag<A, B>;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1bc1dadcb060d1cb)

Comment: Thanks! I modified my code and that works like a charm. :)